# How can we force log-out a user?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, jwt, asp.net-identity, backend

We have a .NET Core WEB API Project that uses Microsoft Identity. We are using [this template](https://github.com/iammukeshm/CleanArchitecture.WebApi).

We want managers to log out users manually by using dashboard. How can we do this? How can we cancel their token etc. ?

I applied the solution given by @MdFaridUddinKirom in comments. I've managed to change the security stamp value for a user, but user still be able to use its token and make requests and our api's accepted it not returned 401 error.

The code in UserService.cs

```
public async Task<bool> UpdateSecurityStampAsync(string email, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {

        try
        {
            var user = await _userManager.Users
            .Where(u => u.Email == email)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(cancellationToken);

            await _userManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync(user);
 
            return await Task.FromResult(true);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return await Task.FromResult(false);
        }
    }
```

The code in the controller:

```
[HttpPost("update-security-stamp")]
    [OpenApiOperation("Update security stamp of a user.", "")]
    [ApiConventionMethod(typeof(FSHApiConventions), nameof(FSHApiConventions.Register))]
    public Task<bool> UpdateSecurityStampAsync(string email, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return _userService.UpdateSecurityStampAsync(email, cancellationToken);
    }
```

Api works and generates 200 response, then I checked database if the user's security stamp value is really change, I saw it is changed. But user still uses api's like nothing happened.

Comment: In Identity you can see `AspNetUsers` table where you would get `SecurityStamp`. If you set new Id on behalf of existing or login user, that perticular user cannot access anything and logout. You can do it by something like this 
       `UserManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync(userId);`

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron what should we set as a new id? Is it matter?

Comment: Anything newId, means randomly generated Id, the point is when the credential wouldn't matched then `AspNetUsers` autometically stop validating that user and cannot persist login.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron I've managed to update security stamp but user did not log out. User accessed api's with same token.

Comment: Include your relevant code snippet in a reproducible way.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron I've edited the post, can you check it?

Comment: Well, thanks for sharing this. Did you checked the token, is there any empact on it after changing the security stamp?

Answer (score 0):

After updating the security stamp depending on the validation interval set the old previous security stamp will still be valid. Hence why you users are still able to use the API as if nothing changed.

You need to set the `ValidationInterval` for the security stamp so that the old security stamps expire. You can do this in the `Startup.cs` `ConfigureServices` method.

Adding this line will mean a user is immediately logged out when their security stamp is updated:

```
services.Configure<SecurityStampValidatorOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ValidationInterval = TimeSpan.Zero;
});
```

For example changing this `TimeSpan` value to `TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15)` would mean the previous security stamps would still be valid for 15 minutes

Edit:
Important to note that changing the security stamp interval to such a short `TimeSpan` will result in more database requests. If it's set to `TimeSpan.Zero` this will result in the database being queried for every request

Comment: Is this compared against the security stamp in the cookie? If so, if a user feels their username and pw has been compromised is the validation Interval set to zero  the best way to invalidate other sessions? Or should I be comparing the security key for changes against any database calls..?